# How to regenerate Auth session in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am stuck in this weird situation where I want to make a user login into my application as soon as he/she verifies their Email Address and enters a Password.

**Problem details**
I have a form where users first have to enter their Email Address and then an OTP will be sent to their email for verification. As soon as they enter the OTP, they get an option to enter a password for their account.
After entering the password, users have to enter their address and contact details. Once everything gets entered, the user has to click the "SAVE" button that saves the details into the database.

**Requirement**
What I want is that when the user clicks on the "SAVE" button, the page gets reloaded and the user logs into his/her account with the entered Email and Password.

**Issue**
Currently, when I try to log in user by refreshing the page, a new session is not created and the system still shows the guest user.

**Things I tried doing to make it work**
I tried many different things on the web but no solution worked for me. I am doing something like below

```
        $user = User::updateOrCreate([
                    'email' => $request->email
                ], [
                    'name' => $request->fullname,
                    'uid' => $request->uniqueID,
                    'phone' => $request->phone,
                    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
                    'address' => $request->address,
                    'state' => $request->state,
                    'city' => $request->city,
                    'pincode' => $request->pincode,
                    'landmark' => $request->locality,
                ]);

        $creds['email'] = $request->email;
        $creds['password'] = $request->password;

        $authAttempt = Auth::attempt($creds);

        if ($authAttempt) {
            Session::put('user', Auth::user());
            return response(['success' => true], Response::HTTP_OK);
        }
```

This is one of the many solutions I tried but it is not working at all. If I try dumping `Auth::id()` before the return statement, I get the authenticated users ID but when the page refreshes on success response, The application goes back to being guest and doesn't show me the name of the user
Can anyone please guide me on how to implement this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try `Auth::login($user)` after you make sure the user is created?

Comment: yes I did that aswell, when the page refreshes, I still see GUEST user

Comment: Is the `APP_KEY` value set in your `.env`?

Comment: Laravel Application shows error if APP_KEY is not set

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here`
```

- 

---

---

> 

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

---

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).